# Issue on dynamic rnn - Migration from TF1x to TF2x

Tags: api, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, recurrent-neural-network, tensorboard

The algorithm supports TF1x.So, I have migrated from TF1x to TF2x since i am running in latest version Python 3.8 | Tensorflow 2x.
I am getting an error for the following lines since dynamic rnn is deprecated from TF2x. It is asking to use keras instead.
Help me to resolve this

```py
#RNN Layer
rnn = tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(RNN_SIZE) 
outputs, final_state = tf.compat.v1.nn.dynamic_rnn(rnn, batch_in, initial_state=rnn.zero_state(BATCH_SZ, tf.float32))
```

I tried converting code from TF1x to TF2x using following link
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate/upgrade

Answer (score 0):

These APIs `GRUCell()`, `dynamic_rnn()` are [deprecated](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/nn/rnn_cell/GRUCell) to use in **TensorFlow 2.x**.

You can use `tf.keras.layers.GRUCell()`, `tf.keras.layers.RNN()` replaced [APIs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GRUCell) for the above apis in **TensorFlow 2.x**.